# String to dictionary word count and display

Tags: python-3.x, ordereddictionary

I have a homework question which asks:

> Write a function print_word_counts(filename) that takes the name of a
>   file as a parameter and prints an alphabetically ordered list of all
>   words in the document converted to lower case plus their occurrence
>   counts (this is how many times each word appears in the file).

I am able to get an out of order set of each word with it's occurrence; however when I sort it and make it so each word is on a new line the count disappears.

```
    import re

def print_word_counts(filename):
    input_file = open(filename, 'r')
    source_string = input_file.read().lower()
    input_file.close()
    words = re.findall('[a-zA-Z]+', source_string)    

    counts = {}
    for word in words:
        counts[word] = counts.get(word, 0) + 1

    sorted_count = sorted(counts)
    print("\n".join(sorted_count))
```

When I run this code I get:

```
a
aborigines
absence
absolutely
accept
after
```

and so on.

What I need is:

```
a: 4
aborigines: 1
absence: 1
absolutely: 1
accept: 1
after: 1
```

I'm not sure how to sort it and keep the values.

Comment: Try printing `counts['absence']`, or counts['after']`.  You have the counts, you just need to print them out.  `sorted(counts) ` just keeps the keys and loses the values.  Have a look at `counts.items()` [which has both keys and values].

Comment: You can't sort dictionaries in Python. You *can*, however, sort a *representation* (think: `list`) of a `dict` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a homework question, so I can't give you the full answer, but here's enough to get you started. Your mistake is in this line

```
sorted_count = sorted(counts)
```

Firstly, you cant sort a dictionary by nature. Secondly, what this does is take the keys of the dictionary, sorts them, and returns a list.

You can just print the value of counts, or, if you really need them in sorted order, consider changing the dictionary  items into a list, then sorting them.

```
lst = list(count.items())

#sort and return lst
```